# Linux, Need to do an update instead of insert in shell script control file

Tags: linux, oracle, sql-update, sh

I have a csv file that I want to load the data in my database table. In my control file I am trying to load the data but I get a constraint error that one of my columns that I am not selecting cannot be null value. So instead of an insert can I do an update in my control file?

This is my error Traffic_Profile_Name cannot be null, but I don't need this column so I rather do an update based on ID only.

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table TRAFFIC_PROFILE_TEMP.
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SERVICE_USER"."TRAFFIC_PROFILE_TEMP"."TRAFFIC_PROFILE_NAME")
```

I only have the ID in my first column in the csv, I want to update the table based on ID is `124` updated the other 5 columns `Y,Y,Y,Y,STANDARD` Here is my csv file below:

```
124,Y,Y,Y,Y,STANDARD
125,Y,Y,Y,Y,BENIGN
126,Y,N,N,N,BENIGN
140,Y,Y,N,N,FRAME
141,Y,Y,N,N,FRAME
```

My control file:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/home/ye831c/migration/log/conv2015_10_LogicalComponent_CosProfile.csv'
BADFILE '/home/ye831c/migration/bad/conv2015_10_LogicalComponent_CosProfile.bad'
DISCARDFILE '/home/ye831c/migration/bad/conv2015_10_LogicalComponent_CosProfile.dsc'
APPEND
INTO TABLE TRAFFIC_PROFILE_temp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID, PE_INGRESS_FLAG, PE_EGRESS_FLAG, CE_INGRESS_FLAG, CE_EGRESS_FLAG, COS_PROFILE_TYPE)
```

Comment: i don't believe you can perform an UPDATE with sqlldr, you can maybe load into a different table without the constraint, and then write a procedure yo do your data manipulation

Comment: so is there an alternative solution that I can do without using sqlldr?

Comment: you might be able to do something with external tables, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm, where you create your csv file as an external table, you can then run updates against internal tables from the external one (i haven't used external tables myself, but it seems possible). As i said before i would be tempted to use sqlldr to load a table without the constraint and then write a procedure which looks at this table and updates the main one from it